# Angular HTTP POST request called 4 times

Tags: angular, http, angular5

I have looked for a solution but I can't find one, could you help me?, this http post request is being called 2 times.

If I include the 2 additional times is calling OPTIONS that would be 4 times.

```
public addEmployeeService(data){
const url = environment.serverUrl + 'enfila/api/organization/CompanyStation/services';
return this.httpClient.post(
  url, 
  data
);
```

}

and this is the class where I'm subscribing from:

```
addEmployeeService(service, i) {
this.personalCareConfigurationService
.addEmployeeService(service)
.subscribe((response) => {
  if(response["Result"]) {
        console.log('this is called twice.');
        this.companyServices[i].checked = true;
        this.toastrService.success("Servicio agregado con éxito.");
      }
    }, (error)=> {
      this.toastrService.error("Error al agregar servicio.");
      console.log('ERROR ', error);
});
```

}

HTML where I'm calling method:

```
<form action="empleados_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" *ngIf="selectedEmployee.Status != 'P'">
<div class="form-check check-rounded" *ngFor="let servicio of companyServices; let i = index;">
    <a href="#" (click)="addEmployeeService(servicio, i);">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <span class="input">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" [checked]="servicio.checked">
                <i></i>
            </span>
            <i class="icon-cart"></i>
            <span class="txt">
                {{servicio.Name}}
            </span>
        </label>
    </a>
</div>
```

[Picture of chrome console with 4 post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPkdh.png)

Comment: Adding `.take(1)` before subscribe will fix it, but let's see why it's happening...

Comment: If you comment out `this.companyServices[i].checked = true;` does it still make four requests?

Comment: I added `.take(1)` and commented out `this.companyServices[i].checked = true` but still two post request are being made.

Comment: can you put a `console.log` at the start of the function to determine whether the function is being called twice or the subscribe callback is being called twice?

Comment: I put a console.log at the start of the function, it was called twice. Thanks, I didn't think about it, was focused on rxjs as the problem.

Comment: Try unsubscribing after the success response :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions that could work for you, generally something like this happens because the observable is triggered twice. Debug to determine whether the function is called twice or the observable is called twice, e.g. add a console.log to the start of the function.

1) add `.take(1)` before subscribe to limit the number of times the subscribe call back is run.

2) the callback/observable method is sometimes hard to reason with (at least for me). Try rewriting your code using `async/await` and see if that helps, e.g.

3) are the two methods (both named `addEmployeeService` both in the same class? could the DOM be calling the wrong one?

```
async addEmployeeService(service, i) {
  try {
    result = await this.personalCareConfigurationService.addEmployeeService(service).take(1).toPromise()
    // Whatever you want to do here
  } catch (err) {
    // Error handling
  }
}
```